# UITable view inside modal presented view controller

Tags: ios, swift, modal-dialog, uikit, storyboard

we have a view controller, have a ui table view inside it, and it's implemented using modal sheet presentation, we are trying to connect the scrolling of suitable view with the modal sheet scrolling like apple maps app, so that when start scrolling while in medium detent the modal become large and when large and reach to the first cell in table view become medium (or next smaller detent). have any one an idea how to implement this ?
[image]

attached a SS from the app.

Answer (score 0):

I have no ability to ask you in comments, so I assume you're using standard modals. If it's true you should use `sheetPresentationController` instead of standard modals.

This way provides you an ability to scroll in the medium detent sheet without automatically expanding.

In addition you can even block expanding, so I encourage you to check this video from WWDC about sheets - https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10063/

Human Interface Guidelines -
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/sheets/